# Open a new form after submit using rules

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, infopath, form, infopath-rules, submit

I am using InfoPath 2013 for developing forms for use in SharePoint 2013. To the question, I am looking for a way (hopefully no code) to open a new form when a user submits a completed form.

Basically i have two buttons. "Submit" and "Submit & New". On the "Submit & New" button, i would like to be able to add a rule following "Close the Form" to open a new one. Seems simple enough, but I cannot figure out how to make this work since the list of "Actions" is limited to "Switch views", "Set a fields value", "Query for data", "Submit data", "Close the form" and "Send data to Web Part".

The reason the form is designed this way is that it combines many tasks and some have different options for submitting. So there are several views and I need this one to open a new copy of itself when the once the user has submitted it.Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: This link helps me with the same problem
http://www.infopathdev.com/forums/p/23515/81553.aspx

Answer (score 1):

I think I might be late answering your question. but for your future reference. On setting up the rules for the 'Submit' button we use, submit using Main Dataconnection and close the form.
for 'Submit & New' button we can use, submit using the Main dataconnection and switch views. In the switch views try using the same default view which will appear when user opens the form.

Thanks
Praneeth

Answer (score 0):

I'm way late, but I found this post and that solution didn't work for me.  The way I got around it was to use the rules to generate what I needed and then submit the form.  After that I added rules to set all the field values individually back to the default without ever closing the form.  Dumb ideas aren't dumb if they work right?  Hope this helps someone!

Comment: I run into an error when trying to submit the form again after doing something like that.

Answer (score 0):

There is an easy option under "Submit Options" > "Advanced > "after submit 'Open New Form' "

I'm you got an answer 2 years ago though...